# Reset label control in code behind to original XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have a C# WPF application with a bunch of labels.
When I run my program it does some checks and wether it the check was positive or not it sets it's corrisponding label to green og red.
These changes is done in my .cs file like:

```
lblCheck14.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

I would like to add a "Reset" button, that reset the application to it's initial start.
How can I easiest implement this?

One way - but I really hope there is a smarter way, is to set them all like:

```
    lblCheck14.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    lblCheck21.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    lblCheck42.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

Etc..

But isn't there a function which I can call that strips away any changes the .cs file have done to the controls in the XAML file? Like make the XAML back to stock?

Sorry for my back explanation. Hope you understand me :)

Best regards

Comment: Maybe because I haven't been able to use any of the answers? Why should I accept an answer that I don't find helpful?
I accept answers that I find helpful, period.

Comment: That is definitely surprising that out of 19 questions, so few have been correct. Just don't be surprised if less people are willing to help you. It's just a heads up to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement styles. You can have a default style to roll back to when you hit reset.

Take a look at this tutorial if you're unfamiliar with them: http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not manipulate UIElements' properties in code. WPF is not winforms. As Yatrix's answer said, implement styles, or even datatemplates and triggers to manipulate different properties of different UIElements acording to some logic (defined in ViewModel or somewhere else). I suggest you to take a look at [WPFTutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)

Comment: You're assuming he's using the MVVM pattern. He may not be.

Comment: @Yatrix that is exactly the problem. People who don't understand or even bother to understand the pattern, and then start hating WPF because they think they can do all the stuff they do in winforms and keep hitting walls all the time.

Comment: I didn't get the impression he was hating on WPF. The MVVM pattern is really only good for sizeable applications. It creates overhead you wouldn't want to incur on a small application. There's nothing incorrect about using WPF in the same manner as a winform (view/code behind).

Comment: @Yatrix I didn't say he hated the platform, I said that if developers don't take the time to learn it they start hating on it, the same as if I open the IDE right now and try to start doing web applications. And IMO, more code to produce the same results that can be obtained with less code (C# code) is wrong. If you can have a solution that is XAML only, it is better to go that way than to have you UI specific behavior hard-coded in procedural code.

Comment: @Yatrix The original question is how to go back to a previous state of an UIElement, for which I agree with you that using styles is a good solution, but then if he's starting to work with WPF I think it is better to let him get the idea that if he doesn't start shifting his mind towards thinking in MVVM terms, he's gonna go thru big pain while trying to work in WPF.

Comment: That's fine, but learning the MVVM pattern is outside the scope of his question. He's looking for a solution to his problem, not a tutorial on MVVM.

Comment: @Yatrix good point. I sometimes lose focus easily. I apologize.